# Wordpress Plugin : Save dynamic settings fields

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm creating a plugin which will diplay categories of the website. For each categort, i want to set an URL.

So i made a table which display all the categeories of the website and a field for each.

How to save each value for each category ?

Here is my code :

```
add_settings_field('name_categories','Categories','categories_cb','plugin-settings','plugin_label_settings');



function categories_cb() {

$settingurl = get_option('url_cat');

?>
<table>
    <tr>

<?php

$categories = get_categories( array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order'   => 'ASC'
  ) );
$urlcat = 0;
foreach($categories as $category) { 

 echo "<tr>"; 

 echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#AEB5B4">'.$category->name.'';
 echo "</td>";
       //deuxieme colonne le nb de presence
 echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$urlcat."' value='".$settingurl."'></td>";

 echo "</tr>";

 $urlcat++;



?>
```

And i want to be able to set an url for each field

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_settings_field` is only for one input field. You could find clues in the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field)

> the callback function needs to output the appropriate html input and
>   fill it with the old value, the saving will be done behind the scenes.

For your purpose, I recommend using `add_settings_field` for each of the categories separately, The code would be something like this:

```php
$categories = get_categories(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    add_settings_field(
        'name_category_' . $category->cat_ID,
        'Category ' . $category->name,
        'categories_cb',
        'plugin-settings',
        'plugin_label_settings',
        array(
            'id' => $category->cat_ID
        )
    );
    register_setting('plugin-settings', 'name_category_' . $category->cat_ID);
}

function categories_cb($args)
{
    $settingurl = get_option('name_category_' . $args["id"]);
    echo "<input type='text' name='name_category_". $args["id"] . "' value='" . $settingurl . "'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now i just have an error with this line : echo '<td><input type="text" name="url_cat[cmby_textarea_field_'.$id.']" value="'.$settingurl['cmby_textarea_field_'. $id .].'"></td>';

Comment: The error is : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']

the code is just : 
echo '<td><input type="text" name="url_cat[cmby_textarea_field_'.$id.']" value="'.$settingurl['cmby_textarea_field_'. $id .].'"></td>'; 

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra dot (`.`) before `]`